# authorizing specific user to use iptables

Tags: php, linux, iptables

I searched everywhere with no answer for this. Here's my problem.

I'm in linux, and I can easily run all iptables functions as root. I want to authorize a specific user to use all iptable functions as well. Everytime I try to access it from the authorized user (other than root), I get this error:

"iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded."

So then I tried chown root:user iptables as well as all the files the symbolic iptables links to so that user can access it. This method works for all other files I want the authorized user to access, but not for iptables.

The reason why I need an answer is because I want to write code in php that allows users to block and unblock IP addresses from accessing any part of the entire server. I have had too many hacking attempts and I want to be able to disable those hackers IP's with a few clicks rather than always accessing shell as root to manually get rid of them.

any ideas?

Comment: This question might be more successfully asked on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), since it pertains more directly to system administration than it does to programming.

Comment: Or on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'sudo' command to allow ordinary users to run commands as root.

This can be dangerous, and you'll need to be very careful to code it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does have a rudimentary system of fine-grain [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).  The key word, though, is *rudimentary*.  [According to strongSwan,](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ReducedPrivileges)

> `iptables` is unable to handle capabilities and does not allow non-root users to insert rules, even if that user has the required capabilities.

You would need root privileges not just to manipulate the rules, but occasionally to load additional kernel modules.

Therefore, `sudo` is your best bet — proceed cautiously, if your local users might also be hostile.  You could also make `/sbin/iptables` SUID root, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You might also look into alternative methods to block brute-force hacking, such as [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) or [PAM ABL](http://pam-abl.sourceforge.net).